# Don't select data from two tables using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables sale and receipt and customer. My tables and result table are

sale

```
date          total     sale_type    cust_id
15-8-2014      50       credit       1
16-8-2014      100      credit       1
17-8-201       200      return       1
18-8-2014      300      return       1
```

receipt

```
date           net_amount           cust_id
15-8-2014          100                  1
16-8-2014          200                  1
17-8-2014          300                  1
```

customer

id      name

1       222

result

```
date            total    net_amount
15-8-2014       50       100
16-8-2014      100       200
17-8-2014      200       300
18-8-2014      300
```

I get these results with my query but i want to get the sum of total from sale table in the case of sale_type='credit' and sale_type='return' .

My query is

```
select date,total,net_amount 
from (select customer.name as customer_name,
             customer.reseller_name as reseller_name,
             sale.date as date, 
             sale.total as total, 
             null as net_amount, 
             2 as sort_col 
      from sale 
        inner join customer 
          on customer.id=sale.cust_id 
      union all 
      select customer.name customer_name,
             customer.reseller_name as reseller_name,
             receipt.date as date, 
             null as total, 
             receipt.net_amount as net_amount, 
             1 as sort_col
      from receipt 
        inner join customer 
          on customer.id=receipt.cust_id) as a 
order by date desc, sort_col desc
```

Any body give any solution please?

Comment: To get sum use:  SELECT    column, colum, SUM(value)
FROM      myTable
GROUP BY  colum, column You can adpat this to your query. This is a should point you in right direction.

Comment: you says like these way,with 2 tables,query is    "select date,total,net_amount,SUM(total) as sum from
  (select  date, total, null as net_amount,SUM(sale.total) as sum,2 as sort_col from sale  
    group by sale_type union
all select date , 
null as total,net_amount as net_amount, 1 as sort_col from receipt)
 as a order by date desc, sort_col desc"   but dont get

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want a `GROUP BY` clause. Also I think you can get rid of the `UNION` and `NULL` business using a`LEFT JOIN` if I've understood correctly then:

```
SELECT S.date, 
       S.total, 
       R.net_amount, 
       SumTable.group_total
FROM sale AS S
  LEFT JOIN  receipt AS R 
    ON S.date = R.date
  JOIN (SELECT sale_type, 
               SUM(total) AS group_total 
        FROM sale 
        GROUP BY sale_type) AS SumTable 
    ON S.sale_type = SumTable.sale_type
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaad82/1/0) showing the result:

```
DATE        TOTAL   NET_AMOUNT  GROUP_TOTAL
-------------------------------------------
15-8-2014   50      100         150
16-8-2014   100     200         150
17-8-2014   200     300         500
18-8-2014   300     (null)      500
```